# How to map vector of functions to vector with functions evaluated at x

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way in numpy to have a vector of `n` different functions that all take one input `x` and then "map" this vector to another vector where the functions have been replaced by the functions evaluated at `x`? For example:

```
funcs = np.array[lambda x: 2*x for i in range(2)]
x = np.array([10,20])
y = np.evaluate_all(funcs, x)
print(y) # [20,40]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a (mostly) pure Python way using `zip`:

```
def evaluate_all(funcs, x):
    return np.array([func(val) for func, val in zip(funcs, x)])
```

A way to use a bit more `numpy`, would be using the [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) wrapper, which allows you to use the `numpy` broadcasting rules (which simplify here to call the function once for each pair of items in `funcs` and `x`):

```
@np.vectorize
def evaluate_all(f, x):
    return f(x)

y = evaluate_all(funcs, x)
```

This has the nice feature that it also allows you to do e.g. `evaluate_all(funcs, 10)` (so `funcs` has some length, but `x` is just a scalar), or `evaluate_all(lambda x: 2*x, [10, 20])` (which is the same as `apply`, but probably slower).

Note, though that the documentation for `numpy.vectorize` states:

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
>   performance. The implementation is essentially a `for` loop.

The two functions differ in their behavior in the case where `funcs` and `x` are not of the same dimension. `zip` just stops at the end of the shorter iterable, while `numpy` will raise a `ValueError` if the shapes are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

using Pandas series and apply :

```
funcs = np.array([lambda x: 2*x for i in range(2)])
x = np.array([10,20])
y = pd.Series(x).apply([x for x in funcs]).values[:,0 ]
print(y) # [20,40]
```

Without List comprehension as suggest in comments :

```
y = pd.Series(x).apply(list(funcs)).values[:,0 ]
print(y) # [20,40]
```

Comment: You could either directly define `funcs` as a `list`, or cast it to a list with `list(funcs)`, instead of writing a list-comprehension with `[x for x in funcs]`.